# Higher Extension Group Question

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra, modules

Suppose we have an associative unital ring $R$, and we have an $R$-module $M$ with a length 3 socle filtration, i.e. write 
$$soc(M) \text{ for the socle of } M,$$

$$soc^2(M) \text{ for the preimage of }soc(M/soc(M)) \text{ under }M\to M/soc(M),$$
 and 
$$soc^3(M) \text{ for the preimage of }soc(M/soc^2(M)) \text{ under }M\to M/soc^2(M)$$
Then we are assuming that $soc^3(M)=M$, $soc^2(M)\neq M$.

From such a module, we can construct a natural element of $\text{Ext}^2(M/soc^2(M),soc(M))$, namely:
$$ 0\to soc(M)\to soc^2(M)\to M/soc(M)\to M/soc^2(M)\to 0$$

Further, one can see from our construction that this element of $\text{Ext}^2$ is the image of the Yoneda product 
$$\text{Ext}^1(soc(M/soc(M)),soc(M))\times\text{Ext}^1(M/soc^2(M),soc(M/soc(M)))\to \text{Ext}^2(M/soc^2(M),soc(M))$$

The above is an example meant to motivate my question- it also is the setting of the situation where I've come across it.

My question is: given an element of $\text{Ext}^2(A,B)$, where $A$ and $B$ are simple modules, is there some way to detect when this extension actually comes from a module $M$ as in the above procedure?  To be very particular and precise, if our higher extension is:
$$0\to B\to V\to W\to A\to 0$$
where $A,B,$ and $V/B\cong ker(W\to A)$ are all semi-simple, 
and $0\to B\to V\to V/B\to 0$, $0\to V/B\to W\to A\to 0$ are nontrivial extensions of semi-simple modules, is there a way of detecting when there exists a module $M$ with socle filtration of length $3$ such that $soc(M)\cong A$, $soc^2(M)\cong V$, and $M/soc(M)\cong W$?

It's possible that this question should be stated in more general terms for clarity, however I thought it might be good to be concrete and particular and be welcome to generalizations that people may know about.

Thanks for any and all help!

UPDATE: Phil Tosteson has pointed out in his answer that an element of $\text{Ext}^2$ coming from a module $M$ of length 3 socle filtration as in my answer must be trivial.

So now I would very much like to know: is the converse true?

To be precise, if we take an element of $\text{Ext}^2(A,B)$ constructed as in the question from two non-split extensions in $\text{Ext}^1(C,B)$ and $\text{Ext}^1(A,C)$, then is it trivial in $\text{Ext}^2(A,B)$ if and only if we can construct a module $M$ as which produces the length 2 extension?

I spent some time thinking about it, but unlike for $\text{Ext}^1$ I don't see any useful consequences or ways of checking if a length 2 sequence gives rise to a trivial class in $\text{Ext}^2$.

Answer (score 3):

I think that such an extension must be zero.  That is, if $M_0 \subset M_1 \subset M_2$  with $M_0 = C$,  $M_1/M_0 = B$ and $M_2/M_1  = A$,  then we have  $f \in {\rm Ext}^1(A,B)$  and $g \in {\rm Ext}^1(B,C)$  and  $fg  = 0\in {\rm Ext}^2(A,C)$.

If you like the "derived" language,  the reason is that $M_1 = {\rm cone~} g$,  and the setup implies that $f$ lifts to a map in ${\rm Ext}^1(A, M_1)$ and so is null-homotopic after composing with $g$.

To show this elementarily using the [definition](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/06XP) of Yoneda extensions,  we see that $0\to  C \to M_1 \to M_2/M_0 \to A \to 0$ admits a map from $0 \to 0 \to M_1 \to M_2 \to A \to 0  $  direct summed with $0 \to C \to C \to 0 \to 0 \to 0$, which in turn maps to $0 \to C \to C \to^0 A \to A \to 0$.

Comment: Thank you!  Can you say more about your last statement?  I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: No worries, it was pretty vague-- I'll try to expand more later.